# Can I find the angle $\theta$ in this structure?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

[image: Image of the structure]

In the image, you can see what information is given. The angle $\varphi$ is given as well. It just isn't assigned any value, but $\varphi < 90^\circ$. The goal is to find the angle $\theta$.

I'm not sure if it's even possible to find the angle from this information, but it seems like it's possible. You can easily calculate $h_3$, but what you need to find is the length of $BE$, so that you can find one of the catheti of the right triangle where $\theta$ is. Note that $AD$ is not a line ($AC$ and $ED$ are not on the same height). For the length $BE$, I thought that you could find the angle at $B$ of the triangle $\triangle EBD$, but I'm not sure how and even if it's possible.

I would appreciate if someone had an idea for how to find angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You can imagine turning D into a hinge and varying the angle CBD by moving D down and to the left, which changes $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, but I thought of the structure as static. I want to know if I can find θ in that current structure.

Comment: The point is that we don't know the angle CBD, and we would need to know it in order to know $\theta$. To put it another way, if we can find two structures with different values of $\theta$ that are both compatible with the given parameters, then we cannot know $\theta$ from the given parameters. Turning D into a hinge is just a way of visualizing how you can vary $\theta$ without varying the given parameters.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean, you're right, thank you.